# How to split data.frame -> apply merge to subsets -> combine into data.frame

Tags: r

I don't really know how to achieve this without using a for loop:

```
x <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')

> x
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"

data <- data.frame(
   x=c('a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
   name=c('one','one', 'two','two','two', 'three', 'four','four','four','four'),
   other=c(1, 4, 5, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 3, 2)
)

> data
   x  name other
1  a   one     1
2  b   one     4
3  a   two     5
4  b   two     3
5  c   two     2
6  a three     4
7  a  four     5
8  b  four     6
9  c  four     3
10 d  four     2
```

I would like to split `data` by the value of `name` and `merge` every subgroup with `x` to fill the "missing rows", getting something like this:

```
> data
   x  name other
1  a   one     1
2  b   one     4
   c   one     0 <- missing row added
   d   one     0 <- missing row added
3  a   two     5
4  b   two     3
5  c   two     2
   d   two     0 <- missing row added
6  a three     4
   b three     0 <- missing row added
   c three     0 <- missing row added
   d three     0 <- missing row added
7  a  four     5
8  b  four     6
9  c  four     3
10 d  four     2
```

And finally, reformatting the `data.frame` like this:

```
> data
   x  one  two  three  four
1  a    1    5      4     5
2  b    4    3      0     6
3  c    0    2      0     3
4  d    0    0      0     2
```

I can achieve it using a for loop, but I am sure there has to be a better solution with `*apply`, `by`, `split` or something like that. Any suggestions?

** UPDATE **

I finally used a little modification to the accepted answer (tnx again, dude!), since I don't really like working with `levels` and I don't care the order of the columns:

```
grid <- expand.grid(x, unique(data$name))
colnames(grid) <- c("x", "name")
data <- merge(grid, data, all.x = TRUE)
data[is.na(data)] <- 0
dcast(data, x ~ name, value.var = 'other')
```

Comment: For your 'finally', see, also, `xtabs`; `xtabs(other ~ x + name, data)` and then `as.data.frame(xtabs(other ~ x + name, data))` for the first part.

Comment: Awesome! I didn't expect another solution like yours! Now I have to understand how `xtabs` works. Thank you very much, mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### More direct:

All you really need is `reshape2::dcast`:

```
# clean up factor levels for prettier results
data$name <- factor(data$name, levels = c('one', 'two', 'three', 'four'))

library(reshape2)
dcast(data, x ~ name, value.var = 'other', fill = 0)

#   x one two three four
# 1 a   1   5     4    5
# 2 b   4   3     0    6
# 3 c   0   2     0    3
# 4 d   0   0     0    2
```

---

#### As asked:

To follow the steps you lay out, first use `expand.grid` to get the combinations, then `merge` with `all = TRUE`, then use `reshape2::dcast` to rearrange:

```
df <- merge(data, expand.grid(x, levels(data$name)), 
            by.x = c('x', 'name'), by.y = c('Var1', 'Var2'), all = TRUE)

df[is.na(df)] <- 0         # replace `NA`s with 0
df$name <- factor(df$name, levels = c('one', 'two', 'three', 'four')) # fix order of levels

library(reshape2)
dcast(df, x ~ name, value.var = 'other')

#    x one two three four
# 1 a   1   5     4    5
# 2 b   4   3     0    6
# 3 c   0   2     0    3
# 4 d   0   0     0    2
```

Comment: That's almost the solution! But the output data.frame has interchanged columns, can you see that?

Comment: Oh, man, you saved my life!!! THANK YOU VERY MUCH for your time. I love StackOverflow and all its communitiy ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try `xtabs`.  No packages are needed.

First put the levels of `name` in order so the columns come out sorted:

```
data$name <- factor(data$name, levels = c("one", "two", "three", "four"))
tab <- xtabs(other ~., data)
```

giving this `c("xtabs", "table")` class output:

```
> tab
   name
x   one two three four
  a   1   5     4    5
  b   4   3     0    6
  c   0   2     0    3
  d   0   0     0    2
```

or use `as.data.frame.matrix(tab)` if output having `"data.frame"` class is desired.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first part you can use `expand.grid`. The logic here to apply is:
Your data:

```
x=c('a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
name=c('one','one', 'two','two','two', 'three', 'four','four','four','four')
other=c(1, 4, 5, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 3, 2)
```

Make this a dataframe:

```
ee<-data.frame(x,name,other)
```

Now use expand.grid to expand and apply all combinations to x and name:

```
dd<-expand.grid(unique(x), unique(name))
```

This looks like:

```
    Var1  Var2
1     a   one
2     b   one
3     c   one
4     d   one
5     a   two
6     b   two
7     c   two
8     d   two
9     a three
10    b three
11    c three
12    d three
13    a  four
14    b  four
15    c  four
16    d  four
```

All your combinations have been created: Now use SQLDF or any merging package:

```
ff<-sqldf("select Var1, Var2, ifnull(c.other,0) from dd left join ee c on x=Var1 and name=Var2")
```

Therefore your output is:

```
    Var1  Var2 other
1     a   one     1
2     b   one     4
3     c   one     0
4     d   one     0
5     a   two     5
6     b   two     3
7     c   two     2
8     d   two     0
9     a three     4
10    b three     0
11    c three     0
12    d three     0
13    a  four     5
14    b  four     6
15    c  four     3
16    d  four     2
>
```

Comment: Thanks! that's a really nice solution to the first part! I prefer using `merge` than `sqldf`, but that's exactly the idea! I will update my original question with your comments :-)

Comment: I really appreciate your help! But @alistaire gave a complete solution, sorry :-(

Comment: No worries . Have a great day. :)